# How do I go about sending data between 2 devices which are paired via Bluetooth in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm still new to Android studio and I'm having a lot of trouble with Bluetooth, I'm currently making an app where I need to send data between devices. I'm letting the phone's  default Bluetooth setup do the pairing but now I need to know how to send the data, I know I need to use input and output streams but I don't know exactly how.

And yes I have searched all over Google, I've followed a lot of Bluetooth tutorials but none of them seem to really explain how to send data from one device to another.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After you establish a secure/insecure connection via bluetooth the rest is just socket programming simply. That is lets think about sending a text. We convert the text to byte and send that by Java OutputStream. In the same manner for the data received we can get it by InputStream.

But remember you need to maintain bunch of code and thread/handler to maintain state and others. Though the basic thing is simply socket programming over Bluetooth socket using the Bluetooth adapter. Have a look at the below repository in github. This creates a chatroom over bluetooth. i.e it sends and receives string data

https://github.com/zahansafallwa/Android-bluetooth-chat-with-emoji/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/zahan/safallwa/donttalk

Specially have a look at the `BluetoothChatService` class. That contains codes related to sending data. [BluetoothChatService](https://github.com/zahansafallwa/Android-bluetooth-chat-with-emoji/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/zahan/safallwa/donttalk/BluetoothChatService.java)

**Edit:**

As per your comment lets think that your devices are paired and also connected. Now you only need to send the text. Declare a `outputstream`

```
private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
```

Suppose you have a string. We convert it to byte. Then get our socket outputstream and send data by `write()` method

```
String message="this is test data";
byte[] send = message.getBytes();
mmOutStream = socket.getOutputStream(); // here socket is the bluetooth socket you establish
mmOutStream.write(send);//this is what sends the message
```

**Remember:**

Edited code is for your understanding only. It is prescribed to use separate thread for sending data.

Comment: So I've spent a good 8 hours now trying to implement the parts I need for this to work.. And it's not working.. You've given me the best information I've gotten so far and I kinda understand what I'm meant to do, I just can't seem to get it to work. Is there any code out there that just handles the point after being paired to sending data from  one device to another? because I think I'm tripping up on the fact this code handles pairing and everything else too

Comment: edited the answer for you. see if you can understand the sending. And i hope u know how to receive the data . i mean read from inputstream.@SparkyMelon

Comment: I understand what that code is doing, I've tried implementing it but I think I've got a lot of semantic errors everywhere.

I need to start from scratch I think, but I don't have any time left (I'm a student, this is for coursework) so I think I've got to give up.

Comment: Why dont you use code on github and understand it throughly. U need not to write whats already is written

Comment: I've been trying to. I currently have 2 different projects which contain what I think is all the code I need for Bluetooth to work, but it isn't working. I can't afford to spend anymore time on the Bluetooth side of the application I'm making, I have to focus on creating a minimal viable product at this point and come back to Bluetooth if I have time.